# Perl - prepend/remove line numbers to a file

Tags: perl

I'm currently writing a Perl script that needs to have an option within a menu that will prepend line numbers to a file and another option to remove those line numbers.

example outputs: `"This is the first line of my file"` should be changed to `"01 - This is the first line of my file"`

and

`"01 - This is the first line of my file"` should be changed to `"This is the first line of my file"`

I've thought of using loops to accomplish this but I have a feeling that there might be a more simple solution. How should I go about solving this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! We prefer it if you show us what you've tried and work with you on it. So give it a shot with loops, that is the right way to do it. If you can't figure it out, edit the question with what you've tried.

Comment: @sharks48 clue `$.` and `s/^\d+//`;

Answer (score 3):

From the command line:

To add the line numbers as requested:

```
perl -ne 'printf("%02d - ",$.);print' < file > newfile
```

To remove the line numbers:

```
perl -ne 's/^\d* - //;print' < newfile
```

### Update

To edit the file "in place" use the -i flag. Also -p instead of -n and print. From the command line:

To add the line numbers as requested:

```
perl -pe 'printf("%02d - ",$.)' -i file
```

To remove the line numbers:

```
perl -pe 's/^\d* - //' -i file
```

Comment: I think I'd put that first one as `perl -pe 'print "$. - "' file`

Comment: @Sobrique, that how I'd do it, however, note the `"01 - "` in the question

Comment: @Sobrique, as far as the -p flag, that's shorter, agreed.

Comment: added Update section with @Sobrique's comment (-p)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use it in a script I am going to extend on nirys answer:
I don't think there is going to be a more simple and mainainable solution than using a loop. One example with `foreach`:

```
sub addLinenumbersToFile {
    my($file) = @_;

    open my $in_handle, "<", $file;
    my @lines = <$in_handle>;
    close $in_handle;
    my $line_count = 1;
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        # modify element directly:
        $line = sprintf("%02d - ", $line_count) . $line;
        $line_count++;
    }
    open my $out_handle, ">", $file;
    print $out_handle join('', @lines);
}
```

You can then call this function with the filename as parameter: `addLinenumbersToFile("inputfile.txt");`

And to return the file to it's original state:

```
    sub removeLinenumbersFromFile {
        my($file) = @_;

        open my $in_handle, "<", $file;
        my @lines = <$in_handle>;
        close $in_handle;
        my $line_count = 1;
        foreach my $line (@lines) {
            my $formatted_line_count = sprintf("%02d - ", $line_count);
            # modify element directly:
            $line =~ s/^$formatted_line_count//;
            $line_count++;
        }
        open my $out_handle, ">", $file;
        print $out_handle join('', @lines);
    }
```

Since the line number remover uses the exact same format the chances of modifying the wrong file by accident are not very big. They could be further reduced by leaving the function after one line didn't match.